# MySQL JOIN two tables with one common condition and one cross table condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select all the galleries from website 5 and join their categories to show categories' names. My question is: are the following three ways of selecting this data identical or they differ as far as the speed is concerned?

1)

```
SELECT *
FROM `gallery`
    JOIN `category`
        ON
            `gallery`.`category` = `category`.`id` AND
            `gallery`.`website` = `category`.`website`
WHERE `gallery`.`website` = 5
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM `gallery`
    JOIN `category`
        ON
            `gallery`.`category` = `category`.`id` AND
            `category`.`website` = 5
WHERE `gallery`.`website` = 5
```

3)

```
SELECT *
FROM `gallery`
    JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM `category`
        WHERE `website` = 5
    ) `category`
        ON `gallery`.`category` = `category`.`id`
WHERE `gallery`.`website` = 5
```

Comment: performance is dependent on whether you have indexes on the columns.

Comment: INDEXES: gallery (website, category), category (website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an inner join, all three are semantically equivalent.

I prefer the first method, because it makes the `join` explicit and puts the conditions for the join in one place.  The others run the risk that changing a constant in a different part of the query might have unexpected effects on the join.

The last one, using a subquery could have some performance impact.  MySQL tends to materialize subqueries.  As a result, the performance might be a bit worse.

EDIT:

As written, they are the same with a `left outer join` but would be different with a `right outer join` or if the `where` condition were on `gallery`.

In an outer join, a filter in the `on` clause does not affect the population from the first table.  The logic for the join is "Return a row if there is a match.  If there is no match for the value in the "outer join" table at all, return the row anyway".  On the other hand, the `where` does do filtering after the join.

Comment: And if I wanted to use outer JOIN? In case some galleries didn't have category?

Comment: How does the first version of the code work? Does it take all galeries from website 5, then ALL categories and then join them? Or it takes galleries from website 5 and categories from website 5 and then join? Isn't it slower than the second version?

Comment: @Craft . . . How they work depends on how MySQL decides to handle the join.  A reasonable way would be to find all the rows in gallery where `website` is 5 and then do the join.  But this depends on indexes.  The three may not have the same execution plans in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 and 2 are exactly the same as to the performance. Query 3 will be significantly slower. Of course the performance of query 1 and 2 depends on indexes. You should create an index on column `website` in table `gallery` and index on columns `id`, `website` in table `category`.

Comment: (`website`, `id`) is a unique index in the table `category`, the same with the table `gallery`. Is that ok? Will that help if I add (`website`, `category`) INDEX on the table `gallery`? Just to get all galleries from one category faster?

Comment: If the unique index is (website, id) then switch the conditions order (category.webiste first). In gallery it's ok.